# LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)"

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I know this question is asked and answered several times
I have already tried almost every solution I could find on Stackoverflow
But solutions given in other questions aren't working
Vectors/templates are used and that's what causing the issue I think
Issue is with template or something I don't know
I need to debug this code and I am not skilled with template and vectors
Using Visual Studio 2017
these are two source code files and rest are auto generated

ConsoleApplication1.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct bank
{
    int accno;
    double accountBalance;
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
};

template <typename typeStruct>

int main()
{


    vector <bank> bankAccounts;

    // declare list of account here. The size of the list is not fixed.
    int input = 0, i=0;
    int *inputPtr = &input;
    menu(inputPtr);
    switch (input)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        i++;
        makeAccount(i,bankAccounts);
        break;
    }

    case 2:
    {
        PrintAllAcount();
        break;
    }

    case 3:
    {
        depositAccount(i,bankAccounts);
        break;
    }

    case 4:
    {

        cout << "Enter account no";
        cin >> i;
        withdrawAccount(i, bankAccounts);
        break;
    }
    case 5:
    {
        printAccount();
        break;
    }
    case 6:
    {
        return 0;
    }
    default:
    {
        cout << "Invalid Input";
    }


    // cases: call functions to perform tasks
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Function file.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
struct bank
{
    int accno;
    double accountBalance;
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
};


void menu(int *num)
{

    int select = 0;
    cout << "Welcome to MadeUp Banking. Select options below:" << endl;
    cout << "\t1. Make new account."
        << "\n\t2. Display all accounts."
        << "\n\t3. Deposit to an account."
        << "\n\t4. Withdraw from an account."
        << "\n\t5. Print account."
        << "\n\t6. Quit." << endl;
    cout << "Selection:\t";
    cin >> select;
    *num = select;
}
// write the remaining functions here
void makeAccount(int i, vector <bank> &vec)
{
    cout << "\n*************************************";
    cout << "\n ACCOUNT CREATION ";
    cout << "\n*************************************";
    cout << "\n Creating bank account number :" << i;
    vec[i-1].accno = i;
    cout << "\nEnter first name:";
    cin >> vec[i-1].firstname;
    cout << "\nEnter last name:";
    cin >> vec[i-1].lastname;
    cout << "Enter starting balance:";
    cin >> vec[i-1].accountBalance;
}

void PrintAllAcount()
{
    cout << "\n";
}

void depositAccount(int i, vector <bank> &a)
{
    int accno, b = 0, m = 0;
    double aa;
    cout << "\n*************************************";
    cout << "\n DEPOSIT ";
    cout << "\n*************************************";
    cout << "\nEnter your Account Number";
    cin >> accno;
    for (b = 0; b<i; b++)
    {
        if (a[b].accno == accno)
            m = b;
    }
    if (a[m].accno == accno)
    {
        cout << "\n Account Number : " << a[m].accno;
        cout << "\n First Name : " << a[m].firstname;
        cout << "\n Starting Balance : " << a[m].accountBalance;
        cout << "\n How Much Deposited Now:";
        cin >> aa;
        a[m].accountBalance += aa;
        printf("\nDeposit Amount is :%f", a[m].accountBalance);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nACCOUNT NUMBER IS INVALID";
    }
}

void withdrawAccount(int i, vector <bank> &a)
{
    int accno, b = 0, m = 0;
    double aa;
    cout << "\n*************************************";
    cout << "\n WITHDRAW ";
    cout << "\n*************************************";
    cout << "\nEnter your Account Number";
    cin >> accno;
    for (b = 0; b<i; b++)
    {
        if (a[b].accno == accno)
            m = b;
    }
    if (a[m].accno == accno)
    {
        cout << "\n Account Number : " << a[m].accno;
        cout << "\n First Name : " << a[m].firstname;
        cout << "\n Starting Balance : " << a[m].accountBalance;
        cout << "\n How Much Withdrawl Now:";
        cin >> aa;
        a[m].accountBalance -= aa;
        printf("\nThe Balance Amount is :%f", a[m].accountBalance);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nACCOUNT NUMBER IS INVALID";
    }
}
void printAccount()
{
    cout << "\n";
}
void sortAcounts()
{
    cout << "\n";
}
// sort the accounts using the account numbers
void deleteAccount()
{
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Make this **shorter** please. For example, nobody is interested in dozens of hard-coded `std::cout` output lines which have absolutely nothing to do with the question.

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate.  Search the internet for "stackoverflow c++ lnk2019".

Comment: The solutions aren't working, I really don't know what's causing it